# How to revert color change of a button on click?

Tags: c#

I have four buttons as i click first tile button it changes color to yellow but as i click second tile the first one doesn`t come in original color

```
   private void metroTile1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btnName = (MetroTile)sender;
        switch (btnName.Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "Fac":
                uc = new facility();
                break;
            case "FC":
                uc = new fCycle();
                break;
            case "FR":
                uc = new feeReceiving();
                break;
            case "MF":
                uc = new memberFacility();
                break;
            case "MT":
                uc = new memberType();
                break;
            case "pan":
                uc = new penalty();
                break;
            case "PD":
                uc = new penaltyDet();
                break;
        }
        heading.Visible = true;
        heading.Text = btnName.Text;
        this.pnl2.Controls.Clear();
        this.pnl2.Controls.Add(uc);
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.metroTile1.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Yellow;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code to switch the first tile back to the original color? I just see the color switching for the tile that has been clicked on.  You probably need something to first change all tiles back to the original color every click, and THEN set the current tile to yellow.

Comment: Exactly this is question how to write the code for back to the original color as i click to another tile.

Comment: @haris.m - If you set the value of `this.metroTile1.Style` to yellow then you have to set the value somewhere else to restore the original value. It doesn't magically know how to change back. How do you think you could do this?